# How to combine these functions into a program? (python)

Tags: python, function

I wrote 2 functions

The first one reads a file and gives number rows in a list:
eg: 
    input 1,2,3=4,5,6=7=9,10,11

```
def read_coordinates():
invoerfile = open("coordinates.txt", "r")
lines = invoerfile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    seperate_coordinate_rows = line.split("=")
    for seperate_coordinate_row in seperate_coordinate_rows:
        print seperate_coordinate_row.split()
```

output:
    ["1,2,3"] 
    ["4,5,6"] 
    ["7"] 
    ["9,10,11"]

and this one weaves 2 lines into eachother:

eg: 
    ["1,2,3"] ["4,5,6"] becomes ["1,4,2,5,3,6"]

```
def Weave_number_rows(row1,row2): #enter 2 rows of numbers as lists
l1 = row1
l2 = row2
woven = sum(zip(l1, l2), ())
print woven
```

how can these 2 work together such that python evrytime weaves the existing row into the next row?

Answer (score 0):

Return it from the functions, and pass the value to the next one:

```
def Weave_number_rows(row1,row2): #enter 2 rows of numbers as lists

    l1 = row1
    l2 = row2
    woven = sum(zip(l1, l2), ())
    return woven  

def read_coordinates():

    invoerfile = open("coordinates.txt", "r")
    lines = invoerfile.readlines()
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        seperate_coordinate_rows = line.split("=")
        for seperate_coordinate_row in seperate_coordinate_rows:
            result.append(seperate_coordinate_row.split())
    return result
```

And to run it:

```
result = read_coordinates()
final_result = Weave_number_rows(Weave_number_rows(result[0], 
               result[1]), (Weave_number_rows(result[2], result[3])))
```